# Azure Logic App Recurrence Trigger: Run on the last Monday of each Month

Tags: azure, recurrence

I have a logic app I'm working on that I'd like to run on the final Monday of each Month.

[image: Logic App Recurrence Trigger]

I've taken a look at some existing, [somewhat similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64711468/run-recurrence-trigger-in-azure-logic-app-on-the-last-day-of-every-month) on how to achieve this, but I've had no luck in finding a simple solution.

Is it possible to specify this simply via an Azure Expression? Or a Trigger Condition?

Any help and guidance on where to look is appreciated. I will be periodically updating this thread with my solutions as I continue to research the topic.

Thanks

**Somewhat near solution:**

The beneath expression does great job at returning the final day of the month. I may make use of this and minus a certain number of days. Obviously this won't always be a Monday.

```
@{addDays(startOfMonth(addDays(startOfMonth(utcNow()),32)),-1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger every Monday and do a check on the first action if the date of the next Monday is still in the same current month, if not, terminate the app.

Or check to add 7days to current date and see if the month is still the same as current month